# Spread operator type checking is too general for generics

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

While working with interface inheritance and generics, I ran across some odd behavior that can result in runtime issues. This is in the most recent version of TypeScript, 5.0.3. In short, a function accepting a generic that extends an underlying interface appears to allow improperly typed values to be returned.

Here's a reproduction of the issue:

```
interface MaybeHasId {
  id?: string,
}

interface HasId extends MaybeHasId {
  id: string,
}

const replaceId = <T extends MaybeHasId>(item: T, newId?: string): T => {
  return {...item, id: newId}
}

const moreSpecificObject: HasId = replaceId({id: "specific id"}, undefined);
console.log(moreSpecificObject.id.length);
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.3#code/FASwdgLgpgTgZgQwMZQAQFkEE8BGUASCAzgJIAmqA3sKqiGQPwBcqREM4A5gDTAC+wUJFiIUqQqQpQAHtDBkiGbHgnkqNOmRZsOYHv0FIA9mDaoYUAA4AbZFDUBeVAB4AKqhlyFS3AWLkAPgAKEGgAWxZXblQwKAB3cmZWdi4ASkjUBwD1WgsIAFcYMCoAOjLQqDDo+hZYhLIBAWBjUwhUMKMLAGVLKCQQOBAkAHkcACs+iBZVCicLGztyIMoa1AAiIl7+waRNNb5o-PkoQdiyVIBuZpMiI2soEusjTiCO7q2BodGJpAgS+keUD0EAAFpdBEA)

Is there a better way to strongly type situations like this? Or is it an underlying issue with TypeScript? I'd either expect there to be a compile-time error with this code, or for "extending" to be more strict while writing inheritance-based types.

Comment: Generic spread in TS results in an intersection, which is often a reasonable approximation but when you overwrite properties then it's not great.  Without a built in spread type operator as requested in [ms/TS#10727](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10727), this is just how it is.  See [ms/TS#50559](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/50559) and the issues it links to. The "better" way is probably to try to emulate such an operator with `Omit` as [shown here](https://tsplay.dev/WJVVkW). Does that fully address the q? If so I'll write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Perfect, thank you! That thread and the connected ones are more than enough info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately TypeScript doesn't have a type operator `{...T, ...U}` that truly corresponds with the results of [object spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#spread_in_object_literals), especially those involving overwritten properties.  See the relevant feature request at [microsoft/TypeScript#10727](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10727) as well as issues linked to it like [microsoft/TypeScript#50185](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/50185) and [microsoft/TypeScript#50559](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/50559).

When spreading objects of specific known types, the compiler suppresses overwritten properties from the result:

```
const specific = { ...{ a: 1, b: "two" }, b: 2 };
/* const specific: {
    b: number;
    a: number;
} */
```

But when spreading values of [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) types, the compiler approximates the result as an [intersection type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types), as implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#28234](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/28234):

```
function generic<T extends { a: number, b: string }>(t: T) {
  return { ...t, b: 2 };
}
/* function generic<T extends { a: number; b: string;}>(
      t: T
   ): T & { b: number; } 
*/
```

As mentioned in microsoft/TypeScript#28234,

> An alternative to using intersections would be to introduce a higher-order type operator `{ ...T, ...U }` along the lines of what [#10727](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10727) explores. While this appears attractive at first, it would take a substantial amount of work to implement this new type constructor and endow it with all the capabilities we already implement for intersection types, and it would produce little or no gain in precision for most scenarios. In particular, the differences really only matter when spread expressions involve objects with overlapping property names that have *different* types. Furthermore, for an unconstrained type parameter `T`, the type `{ ...T, ...T }` wouldn't actually be assignable to `T`, which, while technically correct, would be pedantically annoying.
>
> Having explored both options, and given that intersection types are already used for *Object.assign* and JSX literals, we feel that intersection types strike the best balance between accuracy and complexity for this feature.

---

So that's what's going on with your code.  The value `{ ...item, id: newId }` is seen as having the intersection type `T & {id: string | undefined}`, and is therefore assignable to `T`:

```
const replaceId = <T extends MaybeHasId>(item: T, newId?: string): T => {
  const ret = { ...item, id: newId };
  // const ret: T & { id: string | undefined; }
  return ret;
}
```

While you can't fix this in general, you could address it in your example code by using a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to synthesize a more accurate type via [the `Omit` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittype-keys):

```
const replaceId = <T extends MaybeHasId>(item: T, newId?: string) => {
  const ret = { ...item, id: newId };
  // const ret: T & { id: string | undefined; }
  return ret as Omit<T, "id"> & { id: string | undefined }
}
```

Now you'll get the error you were expecting:

```
const moreSpecificObject: HasId = replaceId({ id: "specific id" }, undefined);
// -> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
// Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.3#code/MYewdgzgLgBBAOBTYBLAZi4MC8MDeMAdMQQIYBcMAjADQwBGlARFAO4hMwC+djMATNwDcAKAD0AKhihIsBMnSZKeETDUNKYAK4BbeogBOo9TAoxtew6K4wJYkSLRawwKCnAwA5ojCHMAHgAVGEQADygfABMIfFNNXX0DXkpoAxQwT24APgAKKEpAgEp8VRgDRCgtAzBY4kIoZIFhES5xKScXNw9vXzTgIJDwqJiyeMsjDTgoNIyhLlzSk3yYQMXCgpgAMli+C0ShbhgROwcRdIiDNFJgRBgAWVIAT30ACVIIAElIkrUUSIB+FLTdKeGgtBznQxXG4wN6fb5hCJgaL3J6vd5fH4wP5Amag8EiGTQMqIeAAG2uiExuAGiOGqOeiDhX1yKAiOgKdF8rC+gKmeOK2CyWKJsHKsFwBDqbMQOjoOPMiB53y4xhgYjE0nAxPFG22BAVqRBMAAPjBnJFEBhfJEDq01OKqjVxaYYgB5HRsoJ0Jh-JjC-XYyK441mi1W9KIFUE0UwHQgcoAZSQqAwwDd9AAVshlszvrhyuTKV8cgbgzAmPJU5gg5weObkRGbYVRBqYABaYUAPx7vb7-d74k1gUeSBgAHJw9ao+PsTEwCBYO8IChPGBSPQybcoCAYFBR7dx0aMuPCKciSAt4QySBPDl40mU4p01mc4Q-tefJ4oAALFsOIA)